Woocommerce wholesale user role setting minimum order quantity to 10 products PHP
I’ve been searching for PHP solutions related to WooCommerce, but nothing I've found has worked for my specific requirements. Here’s the background on my situation:
I need wholesale users to meet a minimum quantity of 10 products to proceed to the checkout page from the cart. I've implemented some PHP code to hide the "Proceed to Checkout" button and any Stripe payment buttons like GPay and Apple Pay if minimum quantity of 10 not met.
While the code works initially when I click Cart button from shop page, load or refresh from the cart page, the buttons reappear if I update the cart quantity (e.g., changing it from 9 to 8 or from 8 to 9). It seems function I have implemented only works when freshly re-fresh the cart page. They should remain hidden or disabled unless the cart meets the minimum quantity of 10 products.
I’ve tried various PHP snippets from StackOverflow which has similar request, but none have resolved the issue. I’m using a Snippet Plugin to manage the PHP code rather than a child theme.
Here’s the code I’ve been working with:
// Set a minimum quantity for wholesale role
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'thumbtoe_minimum_order_quantity' ); // Error message on cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'thumbtoe_minimum_order_quantity' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'thumbtoe_minimum_order_quantity' ); // Error message on cart page

function thumbtoe_minimum_order_quantity() {
    // Set the minimum quantity
    $minimum_quantity = 10;
    // Get the current user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Check if the user has the wholesale role
    if ( in_array( 'wholesale', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        // Get total quantity in cart
        $total_quantity = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        // If total quantity is less than minimum
        if ( $total_quantity < $minimum_quantity ) {
            // Error message
            $error_message = sprintf( 'Retail Partners Minimum order amount must exceed %s items in your cart to proceed.', $minimum_quantity );

            // Display the error message on the cart page
            wc_print_notice( $error_message, 'error' );

            // Remove the Proceed to Checkout button
            add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        $('a.checkout-button').remove(); // Remove the Proceed to Checkout button
                        $('.gpay-card-info-container-fill').hide(); // Hide GPay button
                        $('.apple-pay-button').hide(); // Hide Apple Pay button
                        $('.wc-stripe-cart-checkout-container ul.wc_stripe_cart_payment_methods.active li.wc-stripe-payment-method, p').remove(); // Remove specified Stripe elements
                    });
                </script>
                <?php
            });

            return; // Stop further execution
        }
    }
}

I have searched all related PHP from StackOverflow and applied to my snippet plugin but didn't work.

The issue arises because the script to remove the checkout buttons only runs once when the page loads or is refreshed, and doesn’t re-run when the cart updates. To ensure the buttons stay hidden or disabled until the cart meets the minimum quantity, you can add an event listener to detect changes in the cart total.
jQuery(function($) {
    // Function to hide buttons
    function hideButtons() {
        if ( $('body').hasClass('woocommerce-cart') ) {
            $('a.checkout-button').remove(); // Remove the Proceed to Checkout button
            $('.gpay-card-info-container-fill').hide(); // Hide GPay button
            $('.apple-pay-button').hide(); // Hide Apple Pay button
            $('.wc-stripe-cart-checkout-container ul.wc_stripe_cart_payment_methods.active li.wc-stripe-payment-method, p').remove(); // Remove specified Stripe elements
        }
    }

    // Run initially on page load
    hideButtons();

    // Re-run whenever the cart is updated
    $(document.body).on('updated_cart_totals', hideButtons);
});

